# Rails 3.1 Engines Modules

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rails-engines

When creating a mountable Rails 3.1 engine using

```
rails plugin new my_engine --mountable
```

it creates the engine at `MyEngine::Engine < Rails::Engine`

Is there a way to generate it like the jQuery::Rails engine (Jquery::Rails::Engine), or do I have to do it manually?

I tried these, and of course it didn't work.

```
rails plugin new "my_module/my_engine" --mountable
rails plugin new "my_module::my_engine" --mountable
```

Comment: I bet you doing it manually would've been faster than writing your question ;-)

Comment: Every time I use a generator I would have to go through each file and add my_module.

Comment: That's just my opinion, which you didn't really ask for, but I'm not sure you're generating engines every day. Your question is valid nonetheless, but I'd personally go the quick and dirty way.

Comment: For this application I will need 6 engines as it is currently planned. Not every day is true, but having to do everything manually will be a huge waste of time. Remember that it means the generators would be pretty much useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a peek in the rails source, and you won't like the answer. Plugin generation seems to make the assumption that your engine name isn't nested, like [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.1.0/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/plugin_new/plugin_new_generator.rb#L249).

If you really insist on not doing this by hand, you could try to hack your way through the generator or use a [PluginBuilder](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/PluginBuilder.html) with the `-b` option of the `rails plugin new` command. It doesn't look documented though, a quick search on Google didn't reveal any info, but I may have overlooked something.

Hope this helps.